# Finding specific solution to a system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\alpha\in R$ and homogenous system $\textbf{x'}(t)=A\textbf{x}(t)$ where
$$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & -1 & -3\\ \alpha & -2 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 &\alpha \end{matrix}
\right] $$
I need to show that the system has a non trivial solution where all the elements of the solution vector $\textbf{v}$, i.e $v_1, v_2, v_3$ uphold $\lim_{t\to\infty} v_i = 0\space (i=1,2,3)$ and another non trivial solution where **at least one** of  $v_1, v_2, v_3$ uphold $\lim_{t\to\infty} v_i = \infty$

The characteristic equation of $A$ is $$|\lambda I-A|=(\lambda -\alpha)(\lambda^2+2\lambda+\alpha)$$ so the eigenvalues are $$\lambda_1=\alpha, \lambda_{2,3}=-1\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha}$$
now I know that:

1. if $\alpha < 0$ then $\lambda_1<0$ so one of the solutions is $x^{(1)}=e^{\lambda_1 t}\textbf{v}$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} x^{(1)} = 0$
2. if $0 \le \alpha <= 1$ due to $\lambda_{1,2}=-1\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha}$ at least one eigenvalue $\lambda < 0$ so again like in (1) I have a solution $x^{(2)}=e^{\lambda t}\textbf{v}$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} x^{(2)} = 0$
3. if $\alpha > 1$ then $\lambda_{2, 3}=-1\pm i\sqrt{\alpha - 1}$ and I have a solution $x^{(3)}=e^{-t} \textbf{v}$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} x^{(3)} = 0$

But I'm having a problem with the second part, i.e finding a solution where at least one of the solution vector's elements' limit at infinity is infinity, I think I need to keep the same cases for $alpha$ but I just wasn't able to come up with something

Comment: @Moo I have an eigenvalue $-1$ and a solution in the form of $e^{-t}\textbf v$

Comment: that for $\alpha=1$ but $\alpha$ be less or greater than $1$